# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `MenuItem`, expected a ReactNode

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-router-dom, semantic-ui-react

I am using the `<MenuItem/>` component from [Semantic-Ui-React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu/), in my [Next.js app](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started).
And getting this error in which I can't figure out what is the origin.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `MenuItem`, expected a ReactNode.
    in MenuItem (created by MobileContainer)
    in MobileContainer (created by LinkNavWithLayout)
    in LinkNavWithLayout (created by Context.Consumer)
    in withRouter(LinkNavWithLayout) (created by Connect(withRouter(LinkNavWithLayout)))
    in Connect(withRouter(LinkNavWithLayout)) (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by App)
    in Switch (created by App)
    in App (created by MyApp)
    in Container (created by MyApp)
    in PersistGate (created by MyApp)
    in Provider (created by MyApp)
    in MyApp (created by AppWithReactRouter)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by AppWithReactRouter)
    in AppWithReactRouter (created by AppWithRedux)
    in AppWithRedux
    in Suspense (created by AppContainer)
    in Container (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

The following is what I am rendering,

Essentially if `isLoggedIn` is true it renders the menu items with the appropriate items which are relevant to being logged in and if `isLoggedIn` is false, the items which are irrelevant go away.

```
render() {
  const { children, data, isLoggedIn } = this.props
  const { sidebarOpened } = this.state

  return (
   <Responsive
    as={Sidebar.Pushable}
    getWidth={getWidth}
    maxWidth={Responsive.onlyMobile.maxWidth}
   >
    <Sidebar
     as={Menu}
     animation='push'
     inverted
     onHide={this.handleSidebarHide}
     vertical
     visible={sidebarOpened}
    >
     {isLoggedIn ?
      data.filter(function (nav) {
      if (nav.name === "Login!") nav.name = "Logout!"
       return (nav.name !== "Register")
      })
       .map(nav => {
        return (
         <Menu.Item
          exact
          key={nav.name}
          as={NavLink}
          to={nav.path}
          name={nav.name}
          onClick={this.handleSidebarHide}
         >
         </Menu.Item>
        )
       })
      :
      data.filter(function (nav) {
       if (nav.name === "Logout!") nav.name = "Login!"

       return (nav.name != "Profile") && (nav.name != "Dashboard")
      })
       .map(nav => {
        return (
         <Menu.Item
          exact
          key={nav.name}
          as={NavLink}
          to={nav.path}
          name={nav.name}
          onClick={this.handleSidebarHide}
         >
         </Menu.Item>
        )
       })}

    </Sidebar>

    <Sidebar.Pusher dimmed={sidebarOpened}>
     <Segment
      inverted
      textAlign='center'
      style={{ minHeight: 'auto', padding: '1em 0em' }}
      vertical
     >
      <Container>
       <Menu inverted pointing secondary size='large'>
        <Menu.Item onClick={this.handleToggle}>
         <Icon name='sidebar' />
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item position='right'>

         <Button inverted>
          {isLoggedIn
           ? <Link to="/" onClick={this.logOutuser}>Log out!</Link>
           : <Link to="/login">Log in!</Link>
          }
          </Button>
         {isLoggedIn || <Button inverted style={{ marginLeft: '0.5em' }}>
          <Link to="/register"><span>Register!</span></Link>
         </Button>}
        </Menu.Item>
       </Menu>
      </Container>
     </Segment>

     {children}
    </Sidebar.Pusher>
   </Responsive>
  );
 }
```

Also an important note is I had to switch to [React-Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) because the [Link](https://nextjs.org/docs#with-link) component from Next.js  wasn't working with the aforementioned Menu item from Semantic-React-UI. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The problem seem be to occuring due to the following piece of code

```
{isLoggedIn || <Button inverted style={{ marginLeft: '0.5em' }}>
```

In this case if isLoggedIn is true, the above code would return false which seems to be an invalid child prop for Menu.Item.

Instead you could modify the above code to have a ternary condition and return null for falsy condition

```
{isLoggedIn? <Button inverted style={{ marginLeft: '0.5em' }}: null>
```